# Can't Center Group of images (Class images) side-by-side in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, center

I've already tried some things, but haven't had any luck.

I have a class that scrolls an image upwards in my CSS. I want to be able to create 3 of these images in a row and center them, However since they are float left they cant be centered. If i change it to float center the image will stack on top of each other rather than side by side. Margin left/right auto doesn't seem to work either. I'm not sure what to do

My CSS Code:

```
.pic {
  border: 3px solid#fafafa;  
  float: left;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20;
  overflow: hidden;
   }
.aligncenter {text-align:center} 

/*VERTPAN*/
.vertpan img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: margin 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: margin 1s ease;
       -o-transition: margin 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: margin 1s ease;
          transition: margin 1s ease;
}

.vertpan img:hover {
  margin-top: -250px;
}
```

My HTML Code:

```
<div class = "vertpan pic"><img class="aligncenter" alt="climb" src="http://i.imgur.com/XIaOaId.jpg" /></div>
<div class = "vertpan pic"><img class="aligncenter" alt="climb" src="http://i.imgur.com/69K8qMU.jpg" /></div>
<div class = "vertpan pic"><img class="aligncenter" alt="climb" src="http://i.imgur.com/XIaOaId.jpg" /></div>
```

I've tried centering in every way I know of but nothing has worked. I'm sure it's something simple, I just don't fully understand HTML or CSS as of right now that's the problem.

Comment: If you want to see the 3 images, scroll to the bottom of the page of thejasgroupinc.com

Comment: just for info, `float:center` is a non-existing css declaration so in that case the divs will be treated as non-floating block elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the all the DIVs inside a container. Give it a width and use margin auto.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class = "vertpan pic"><img class="aligncenter" alt="climb" src="http://i.imgur.com/XIaOaId.jpg" /></div>
<div class = "vertpan pic"><img class="aligncenter" alt="climb" src="http://i.imgur.com/69K8qMU.jpg" /></div>
<div class = "vertpan pic"><img class="aligncenter" alt="climb" src="http://i.imgur.com/XIaOaId.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
width: 920px;
margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was an simple easy solution

Comment: Oopz, I think you forgot to mark it as the answer if its right :/

Answer (score 10):

Use `display:inline-block` on `.pic` instead, and put them in a wrapper with `text-align:center`.

for instance the HTML should be something like this:

```
<div class="picwrapper">
    <div class="pic">fancy picture 1</div>
    <div class="pic">fancy picture 2</div>
    <div class="pic">fancy picture 3</div>
</div>
```

And additional CSS:

```
div.picwrapper {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
div.pic {
    /* remove float:left here */
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Hope this helps, 
cheers.

Jeroen

Comment: Why using text-align center to center align DIV ?

Comment: in this way everything inside the wrapper div get's centered without having to put a fixed width on the wrapper. So instead of centering the wrapper div itself, you center the nested inline blocks.

Comment: But text-align should be used to align text not elements like DIV, right ?

Comment: `text-align` aligns inline elements (not only text), like spans and paragraphs which are inline by default. Setting a div as `inline-block` will transform the, by default block element, to an inline element.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. works well, much simpler of a solution, and doesn't require a fixed width on the container.